# Bibliographic troubleshooting

Tags: biblatex, winedt

I face the following issues in reference list. When I type, say, "Ann. Inst. H. Poincar\'{e} Anal. Non Lin\'{e}aire " in  WinEdt in biliography, the output is
"Ann.---Inst.---H.---Poincar\'{e}---Anal.---Non Lin\'{e}aire", (a dash indicates a space)
with extra space between words. This always happens, for example, when a reference that I am citing is at least three lines!

Comment: Hi!. Can you post a MWE. What style are you using?. The output really has `\'{e}` and not `é`?.

Comment: do your long references contain a url at the end?  the usual reason for stretched-out references is the presence of a long, unbreakable element at an "inconvenient" location in the output.

Comment: Addendum to @barbarabeeton ... and LaTeX tries to justify the rest spacing/stretching white space.

Comment: Yes, it contains a URL at the end. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: If you are using package `hyperref`, use the option `breaklinks`, else `\usepackage{url}` with a suitable option.

Comment: @Johannes_B you are right, problem resolved, thanks!